# weired zsh behavior: How to debug?

Tags: zsh

When I enter

```
$ echo $USER:
```

I get

```
robin:
```

Which is fine. But when I enter:

```
$ echo $USER:a
```

I get

```
/Users/robin/robin
```

that is

[MY_CURRENT_DIR]/[MY_USER_NAME]

That behavior seems weired to me. Can anyone tell me how to debug this? I already checked for an alias, but that's not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:a` is being interpreted as a modifier on the `$USER` parameter, treating it
as a filename and converting it into an absolute path by prepending your
current directory.  This is covered in the **history expansion** section of the
`zshexpn` manpage in the [**modifiers** subsection](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers).

You can prevent this by surrounding the variable name with curly braces:
`${USER}:a`.  In general it's a good idea to do that anytime that something
other than whitespace or a quote character comes after the variable name.